# Looking for a certain .Net ORM

Tags: asp.net, .net, database, orm

I like working with SQL code and I hate taking the time to create a class for every query.If it's something I'll use all the time then I don't mind but I'm looking for a ORM that I can do something like the following:

```
var obj = ....("SELECT Id, Name, Description FROM MyTable");
...Show(obj.Id + obj.Name + obj.Description);
```

So, it can be used like a class but I didn't have to create a class for it. Also, and I know I'm asking a lot with this one but can it also be used with .net 2.0? I have clients that still use it and won't upgrade. Anyway, I know the .net 2.0 thing is a stretch but figured with stuff like LinqBridge maybe it's a possibility.

thanks

Comment: Why was this voted to be closed? Seems like a perfectly valid question to me

Comment: Thanks.
I'm a little shocked that this was closed. I don't see how anyone might argue or debate this. Either they know of an ORM that does this or not. Where is the debate?

Comment: Yeah, i don't see why it would be closed either.  Particularly without any comment by any of the closers.

Comment: Well, since some dark forces chose to close this question, this was my answer: Rob Conery created Massive, a simple ORM-like library which does just that.

https://github.com/robconery/massive

Comment: hey, nice. I use his SubSonic right now actually. I only wish you can do this with 2.0 but I figured as much.

Answer (score 4):

I imagine it's quite possible to create an ORM that will instantiate `dynamic` types based on the returned values, without the need to create classes for intermediaries.

However, this would require .net 4, with the DLR built-in.  This couldn't be used in .net 2 without a lot of rework, and adding in a DLR to make it work.

I don't know of any such ORM out there though.

Comment: The issue is also the syntax. C# 3.0 would never compile that, even if there was DLR in .NET2. Does VB.NET allow late-binding?

Comment: @pst - I doubt it was intended to be valid syntax, he was just showing how he'd like to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Linq2Sql, it sounds like something you'd appreciate. Alternatively try Entity Framework, but it's a bit heavier and requires more setup (in my experience).

Comment: I don't think you actually read his question.  L2S and EF require that you create classes for data transfer objects.. he doesn't want that.

Comment: You could use T4 templates with EF to autogen the classes so I don't think this answer is that unreasonable

Comment: Neither LinqToSql or EF work on .NET 2.0 (.NET 3.5 is the minimum).  NHibernate does work on .NET 2.0 though.